# Converting offline Windows 8 to VHD for Hyper-V (p2v)

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-8

here's my current config:

1. I have an offline SSD with a single ~240Gb partition that was running in my old laptop.
2. I no longer have access to the laptop.
3. I have a new eSata enclosure and would like to boot from a VHD of the old image, externally, running on my new Win8 machine using Hyper-V.

I would like to know if:

1. This is possible with current tools,
2. If anyone could recommend a utility to do the p2v conversion on the disk.

I checked DiskToVHD from sysinternals, but it says it only supports up to 128Gb partitions.  I found a couple of other utilities, but couldn't find confirmation that they supported Win8.

Comment: so you have the 240gb disk in the new esata enclosure, hook that up to you w8 workstation. Then create a new vm when it asks for the destination disk it will give you the option to import from a physical disk. This is an easy way to p2v when you just have the disk.

Comment: Why the downvote here? This is a clear question IMO and the details are here.

Comment: Thanks @tonyroth I will look at that as an option. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Create a VHDX using the Disk Management MMC that is at least as large as your SSD. Attach the VHDX. Then use something like [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) to copy the SSD to the VHDX. Once that is complete, detach the VHDX, create a new VM and attach the VHDX instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks longneck, this seems like a reasonable approach, though they don't offer support on the free version. I'm going to try @tonyroth's suggestion first and if that doesn't work I'll consider the commercial license on DriveImage XML.  Cheers.